# cannot open the file because the open options are incorrect

Tags: c#, photoshop-cs4

Im using photoshop library in C# application.

```
public static ps.ApplicationClass app

 createPreviewThumbnail(filepath);//looks like "http://192.26.1.105/Connect/testjob/test.PSD"

  public static void createPreviewThumbnail(string sourcePath)
    {
     app = new ps.ApplicationClass();
     Photoshop.Document doc = app.Open(sourcePath, null, null);
      ......
    }
```

This code works fine but some times I get this Exception that `cannot open the file because the open options are incorrect` What may be the reasons for this?

Comment: I'm guessing (just a rough guess) that the open options may be incorrect. Where is sourcePath defined?

Comment: again, where is the sourcePath variable coming from?

Comment: sourcePath is remote path..

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in the filepath.

I've had this error message twice on a piece of code I've been working on recently. The first time, the error was due to two different kinds of files in the directory path. The code would only work if there were no other files in the directory.

After I solved that problem, the same error message came up. I tried changing the file path, but it didn't work. However, when I changed the filepath back to what I had originally, it worked. I may have had a typo or error before and didn't know it.

Hope that helps anyone getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when trying to open a file that was in my Dropbox folder.
Since Dropbox has "online only" files that are really just a pointer to a file that will download when clicked on, my Photoshop could not open these file *while Dropbox was turned off* . Turning it on fixed this error message

To readers of this issue:
This indicates if the path is correct, is there some other issue with the file pointers? Is the file locked? that sort of thing.